# Algorithm for heavily restricted Knapsack problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem, multiple-choice

**I have a following problem to solve:**

1. We have 53 weeks in a year, for each week we need to choose one model from the list: [A1, A2,....,F149, F150]. In total around 750 models in 6 classes: A,B,C,D,E,F.
2. Models can repeat and each has a specific value from around 3 to 10 and a weight. *The goal is to achieve a target total value of 280+-5% with a minimal weight by the end of the year.*
3. However there are a ton of restrictions. For example:

- Models must be held for at least 4 weeks in a row. If we have chosen A1 for week 1, then we need to choose A1 for weeks 2,3,4;
- If we have chosen model classes E,F then, after they end, we cannot choose E, F for another 4 weeks.
- Throughout the year we can only choose 23 models of class D.
- an so on

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Based on a target value create a corridor of allowed values throughout the year:
   [Corridor looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGdPX.png)
2. Starting at week 1, choose a random model for the week from the list of allowed models -> Based on the choice modify the list of allowed models for next weeks
3. If our choice satisfies the criterion (also lies within a corridor), then week+=1. If not, delete this possibility.
4. If there is no more models for this week, go back one week, delete the possibility we have chosen before and choose random from what's left.

Pictorially the algorithm is like following the branches of a tree. If the branch is bad, return back to the fork and cut off the bad branch.

This algorithm can generate a random valid solution (in about 5 to 80 minutes with a mean time of 25 minutes). Then I need to generate more of those and choose one that has the least weight. Which is not a very good approach, I presume.

**Question**

The question is: what is the optimal way to solve the problem? The priority is to find the solution with a minimal weight and a target value and not the fastest algorithm. But it should at least end in a final amount of time =)

The problem statement above is a bit oversimplified and due to the complexity of calculations and the amount of combinations, there is no way to consider and compare all combinations.

Comment: does "Models must be held for at least 4 weeks in a row." apply to all models? if so "Throughout the year we can only choose 23 models of class D" seems unneccesary.

Comment: it is necessary. There are 53 weeks in a year, if you choose some Ds for weeks 1-20 (say D1 for 1-4, D5 for 5-8, ... D150 for 16-20), you are not allowed to choose any Ds any more.

Comment: ok, but you only get to make 15 choices in total (since you have to keep every model for 4 weeks)

Comment: If this is a practical problem (for work or science) and not school/contest i would look into modeling it as a Mixed Integer Program. It won't take too long and the solvers are really strong. It _might_ give you what you want with not too much effort.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into Mixed Integer Programs.

Comment: There are more than 15 choices, since you must have AT LEAST 4 weeks in a row, you are allowed to have more